# Trouble with selecting elements with JS (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

In my HTML page, I have only header, main and footer tags. I have to append some content in all of them, and every time I select any of the elements in console it works just fine and does job. As soon as I get to my script.js page and pass the same path, it returns null or undefined. How do I fix this?

I've tried different methods, like: document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0] (as it returns node list), querySelector, and each of them works in console but not in script.

var mainSection = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]; 
This turns undefined when I console it.
In console, however, path works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you show your actual code please?

Comment: It is quite impossible to say what the problem might be without seeing the code.

Comment: Try putting your `script.js` at the bottom of the page. It's possible you are adding your `javascript` and executing it before the DOM elements exist.

Comment: var mainSection = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]; This turns undefined when I console it. In console, however, path works perfectly fine.